# JS HTTP post YAML

Tags: javascript, rest, http

I am unable to post a yaml throught http in js. The code works when I used JSON.stringify(text) for body and have content-type application/json. If I use YAML stringify, body on server side is just {}.
I have areatext where I enter a text (like yaml format) in html e.g.

```
martin:
  name: Martin D'vloper
  job: Developer
  skill: Elite
```

Client:

```
$('#create-yaml2').on('click',async function () {
    var text = $('#yaml-create').val();
    // console.log(text)
    var textYAML = YAML.stringify(text);
    var options = {
      hostname: 'myhostname',
      port: 80,
      path: `/api/postyaml`,
      method: 'POST',
      body: textYAML,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/x-yaml'
      }
    };
    var executeReq = http.request(options);
    executeReq.write(textYAML);
    executeReq.end();
  });
```

EDIT:
Function in server side, that prints not an empty {} when posting JSON.

```
exports.functionCalled = async function (req, res) {
    console.log('\n\n\n\n')
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log('\n\n\n\n')
    try {
        res.send(`RECEIVED`);
      } catch (upgradeErr) {
        res.status(422).json({
          message: `Failed`,
          error: upgradeErr
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `YAML.stringify`, are you using the [YAML npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml) ?

Comment: Yes, that's the module I use. I think my problem is that I have a textarea in thml, where I the text is entered, but dont know how to go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a string coming from HTML, so you don't need to call `YAML.stringify` once again - text is already a string.

```
$('#create-yaml2').on('click',async function () {
    var text = $('#yaml-create').val();
    // console.log(text)
    var textYAML = text;
    var options = {
      hostname: 'myhostname',
      port: 80,
      path: `/api/postyaml`,
      method: 'POST',
      body: textYAML,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/x-yaml'
      }
    };
    var executeReq = http.request(options);
    executeReq.write(textYAML);
    executeReq.end();
  });
```

You may want to do something like

```
$('#create-yaml2').on('click',async function () {
    var text = $('#yaml-create').val();
try {
  YAML.parse(text)
} catch(e) {...}

...
send request
```

to make sure there was a valid YAML provided

Answer (score 0):

`YAML.stringify` converts a JavaScript data structure to a string containing YML.

You don't have a JavaScript data structure, you just a string containing YML.

Almost. You have an error in it. You can't use a raw `'` in a YML string that isn't quoted.

So:

## Fix your YML:

```
martin:
  name: "Martin D'vloper"
  job: Developer
  skill: Elite
```

## Don't double encode it:

```
var textYAML = $('#yaml-create').val();
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by not double encoding it? Ive now fixed my yaml file, it doesnt have ' or " in it. Its still {} on server side.

Comment: If you have a string containing YML and pass it through `YAML.stringify` you will end up with a string containing a YML representation of a string containing YML. Which is silly, and not what you want.

Comment: There's no way to tell why your server-side code is giving you `{}` because you haven't provided a [mcve] that shows us what the server is doing to parse the YML.

Comment: my server side is fine, when I post JSON instead of YAML it received it and print the request.body as not an empty {}

Comment: What makes you think that your server's ability to process a JSON formatted request body means that it can also process a YML formatted request body?

Comment: I have updated question with server side function that prints req.body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222967/discussion-between-powisss-and-quentin).

Comment: @Powisss — So where's the bit which parses the YML? If you were using, for example, Express.js, then you'd have some middleware to do that. Provide a [mcve].